# consecutive number of events without NA

Tags: r

How can I extract the number of consecutive events without an empty event, from a vector?

I've tried `rle()` but it doesn't give me what I am looking for.

With this type of data

```
data=c(NA,NA,seq(1,4,0.5),NA,0,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(10,-5,10),NA)
```

I want to be able to know the length of the different sequence of events without a NA. For this case the output should be: `7, 2 and 10`.

I also need the positions of each sequence of events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rle` works here:

```
data=c(NA,NA,seq(1,4,0.5),NA,0,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,runif(10,-5,10),NA)
with(rle(!is.na(data)),lengths[values])
## [1]  7  2 10
```

You can get lengths and positions like this:

```
with(rle(!is.na(data)),cbind(length=lengths[values],position=cumsum(c(1,lengths))[values]))
##      length position
## [1,]      7        3
## [2,]      2       11
## [3,]     10       17
```